# ImageView.setImageResource returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using an ImageView within an actionLayout for a menu item, but when i try to set the image resource I get a NPE :/ I'm not sure what i could be doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Menu.xml

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/add_note"
            android:icon="?attr/add_note_icon"
            android:title="@string/add_note"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:title="user_image"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/profile_icon"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

        <item
            android:title="@string/themes"
            android:id="@+id/themes"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

    </menu>
```

profile_icon.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_icon_main"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user_image_blue"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

java

```
CircleImageView profile_icon = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_icon_main);
profile_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_image_black);
```

Comment: try this: int id = getResources().getIdentifier(user_image_black, "drawable", getPackageName());
setImageResource(id);

Comment: I need a little more context: from which part of your app are you trying to access the ImageView?

Comment: I'm trying to access from the MainActivity

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to do is change the image of the profile_icon (which is in my menu on my toolbar on my Main activity) when a user signs in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `ActionView` (as well as its children) in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. Note that you have to write `actionView.findViewById(...)` because you want to access a child `View` of the `ActionBar` not a child `View` of the `Activity`'s content `View` (which is usually inflated from the layout resource you refer in `setContentView()`).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.user_image);
    View actionView = menuItem.getActionView();
    actionView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    ImageView imageView = actionView.findViewById(R.id.icon_main);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_image_black);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I knew I was accessing incorrectly somehow lol thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CircleImageView profile_icon = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_icon_main);
profile_icon.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(user_image_black, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

This will work if you want to set up image programmatically.